# Accord.net's Cobyla optimization Constraints

Tags: vb.net, optimization, constraints, accord.net

Defined constraints for  Accord.net Cobyla's optimization are not working as expected

I need to optimize the following excel sheet calculation in vb.net using Accord.net Cobyla's method. I am testing with a total of 4 variables:

```
Dim f1 As Func(Of Double(), Double) = Function(x)


                                              Dim var1 As New ArrayList
                                              Dim objsheets As Excel.Sheets = Nothing
                                              Dim app2 As Excel.Application = TryCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
                                              'Access excel sheet
                                              file = "C:\kws_work\Blade.xlsx"
                                              books = app2.Workbooks
                                              objsheet = books(1).Sheets(2)

                                              'fill target cells-x0[ind] with variables x[ind]
                                              For ind = 0 To x.Count - 1

                                                  objsheet.Range(x0(ind)).Value = CInt(x(ind))
                                              Next
                                              Dim res As Double
                                              res = objsheet.Range("_res1").Value
                                              'Return the calculated value to optimizer
                                              Return (res)
                                          End Function
```

constraints are defined as follows:

```
        Dim f5 = {New NonlinearConstraint(4, Function(x) x(0) >= 29),
        New NonlinearConstraint(4, Function(x) x(1) >= 29),
        New NonlinearConstraint(4, Function(x) x(2) >= 29),
        New NonlinearConstraint(4, Function(x) x(3) >= 29)
}
```

- First, I expect the all variables x(i) input in the excel sheet to have different values, but they are all identical.
- Second, I'm expecting the optimizer to start at x(i)>=29, but but it starts at 0, and finishes at 29.
- Additionally, is there a way to limit x(i) to integers in the nonlinear constraints
- The number of variables/constraints is actually subject to changes, I can manage the variable number of x(i), but I am still looking for a way to get a variable number of constraints. If Something like the code below:

  Dim f5 = {New NonlinearConstraint(NumberOfVariables, for i=0 to NumberOfVariables-1
  Function(x) x(i) >= 29)
  next}

or Better:

```
Dim f5 = {New NonlinearConstraint(NumberOfVariables, for i=0 to NumberOfVariables-1 
Function(x) aListofdoubles.contains(x(i)))
next}
```

Comment: I used "System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine" to check the values of each x(i): they are not identical, but way to close! is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer this one: 
"*is there a way to limit x(i) to integers in the nonlinear constraints*"

No. Cobyla is for **continuous** variables. In theory you can use the constraint

```
x*(1-x) = 0
```

to force `x` to be a binary variable. In practice this does not work.

For an NLP problem with integer constraints, you really need an MINLP solver (or use tricks such as linearization or piecewise linear functions).

I don't understand your model. Most of your "nonlinear constraints" look just like bounds. Those are linear. Of course I have no idea what is happening in the Excel part.

In general I would recommend to write the model down in math and think about the mathematical model a bit before starting to code. This often helps to get a better understanding of the problem. You seem to have a function based on some Excel formulas. If you want to stay in Excel, it may be better to use the Excel solver. In addition Excel solver can handle MINLP problems. Otherwise I suggest to extract the underlying math and formulate the complete problem outside Excel and only exchange data (input or solution data) with Excel.

Comment: Thank you for the response Erwin. Any idea about the constraints not being respected: I input "x(i)>=29" but it actually does "x(i)<=29". is it because I use linear constraints in a NLP problem? or is it just a behavior specific to the accord.net library?

Comment: I don't know what Accord is doing with these constraints. Cobyla itself is a well-known solver. It is not state-of-the-art, but it can be useful when gradients are hard to come by. Cobyla supports `>=` inequalities only (`<=`constraints have to multiplied by `-1`). I assume you checked the return code. I suggest to start with some smaller test cases, without Excel, and see if you can reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Also note that Cobyla supports lower and upper bounds on decision variables directly. I don't know how to specify them in Accord but Cobyla certainly supports them. You specify bounds as general inequality constraints. I think that may be the cause of the problem.